# How to filter elements in array in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

If I have a JavaScript object like this:

```
{"products":
    [
        {
            "id":"6066157707315577",
            "reference_prefix":"BB",
            "name":"BeanieBaby",
            "product_line":false,
            "has_ideas":true
        },
        {
           "id":"6066197229601550",
           "reference_prefix":"BBAGS",
           "name":"BlackBags",
            "product_line":false,
            "has_ideas":false
        }
    ],  
    "pagination": {
        "total_records":4,
        "total_pages":1,
        "current_page":1
    }
}
```

How do I write a function in js to loop over each pair and only return the elements of the array where  `has_ideas === true`?

I have started with this but I'm stuck.  Clearly I am new to this.  Any help appreciated.

```
product: function(mybundle) {

    var json = JSON.parse(mybundle.response.content);
    for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        var obj = json[i];

        if (json[i].id === "has_ideas" && json[i].value === true) {
            return json;
        }
       return [];
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out each pair by simply checking that property:

```
var json = {"products":[{"id":"6066157707315577","reference_prefix":"BB","name":"BeanieBaby","product_line":false,"has_ideas":true},{"id":"6066197229601550","reference_prefix":"BBAGS","name":"BlackBags","product_line":false,"has_ideas":false}],"pagination":{"total_records":4,"total_pages":1,"current_page":1}}

var stuff = json.products.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.has_ideas === true
});

console.log(stuff);
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/bsyk18cb/

Comment: This is close but what i need returning is a new json string containing each product that has_ideas===true

Comment: as in {"products":[
    {
      "has_ideas": true, 
      "product_line": false, 
      "id": "6066157707315370577", 
      "reference_prefix": "BB", 
      "name": "BeanieBaby"
    }, 
    {
      "has_ideas": true, 
      "product_line": false, 
      "id": "6065458112963554815", 
      "reference_prefix": "DEMO", 
      "name": "Fredwin Cycling (Demo)"
    }
  ]}

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
product: function(mybundle) {
    var json = JSON.parse(mybundle.response.content);
    for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        if(json[i].has_ideas === true){
            return json;
        }
        return [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to check the "has_ideas" attribute and if true, return the id.

```
product: function(mybundle) {

    var json = JSON.parse(mybundle.response.content);
    for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
         if (json[i].has_ideas === true) {
            return json[i].id;
        }
       return [];
    } 
}
```

Comment: What i need returning is a new json string containing each product that has_ideas===true.

Answer (score -1):

Use code below.

this will return array of elements having `has_ideas=true`

```
var json = "{'products':"+
    "["+
        "{"+
            "'id':'6066157707315577',"+
            "'reference_prefix':'BB',"+
            "'name':'BeanieBaby',"+
            "'product_line':false,"+
            "'has_ideas':true"+
        "},"+
        "{"+
           "'id':'6066197229601550',"+
           "'reference_prefix':'BBAGS',"+
           "'name':'BlackBags',"+
            "'product_line':false,"+
            "'has_ideas':false"+
        "}"+
    "],"+
    "'pagination': {"+
        "'total_records':4,"+
        "'total_pages':1,"+
        "'current_page':1"+
    "}"+
"}";

function filter(){
    var jsonArr = [];
    var gList = eval( "(" + json + ")");
    alert(gList.products.length);
    for(var i=0;i<gList.products.length;i++){
        if(gList.products[i].has_ideas){
            jsonArr.push(gList.products[i]);
        }
    }
    return jsonArr;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wb6e7g6z/1/)